# I would like to know if there are any alternatives to netlify.com?

Tags: reactjs, github, deployment, material-ui, netlify

I have been using netlify.com and its great but when I try and post a project with API or MUI/react the project always fails to load. Are there any alternative sites that are FREE that I could use just to show a preview of the site without having to use netlify/github?

Comment: Question asking for recommendation for tools/software or similar is off-topic here on SO. Try some other page for these kinds of questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitHug Pages, Heroku, Vercel, Firebase and Netlify it self